# JS: Разбить длинную строку на части для отправки $.ajax'ом

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть html-страница, с которой нужно отправить через $.ajax очень длинную строку символов РНР-обработчику на другом домене. Строка со временем будет постоянно увеличиватся и в какой то момент может иметь уже десятки или даже сотни тысяч символов. Протестировал и выяснил что длина урла в аякс-запросе может быть около **4800 символов**, больше Аякс не пропускает, по крайней мере в Хроме. Первое что приходит в голову — разбить всю строку на части не больше 4800 и отправить все части поочередно, с каким то интервалом, а потом в обработчике собрать все назад в единое целое. Другие решения приветствуются

Мой запрос на аяксе:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var veryLongString = 'Very long stringggggggggggg';
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://mydomain.com/myhandler.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'myCallback',
        data: {key: veryLongString},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Для разбивки на части как элементы массива нашёл (опять же другие идеи приветствуются):

```
veryLongString.match(/.{1,4800}/g);
```

А что дальше делать — не знаю. Как то через setInterval() или как?

ps. Как собрать на стороне обработчика пока вопрос не беспокоит, пока только как отправить частями (хоят кто его знает, может сразу нужно и обработчик учитывать...)

**При переключении на method: 'POST'**

пытаюсь отправить около 12000 символов но все равно в консоле получаю ту же самую ошибку (со словом GET почему то) и запрос не отправляется. Ошибка:

```
GET http://mydomain.com/myhandler.php?callback=jQuery111103417691031936556_1…20%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BB%25D1%258F%2522)&_=1445978068736

send @ jquery-latest.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax @ jquery-latest.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ mypage.html:2014
m.event.dispatch @ jquery-latest.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-latest.min.js:3
```

Строка 2014 это `$.ajax({`

Comment: Используйте POST и не нужно выдумывать костылей.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но для POST запросов лимитов на строку нету. (Вернее, они есть, но вы очень вряд ли в них упретесь).

Comment: На самом деле вы **не** переключились на POST. Если вы действительно хотите использовать JSONP -- POST вам не поможет.

Comment: Мне нужно передать данные на другой домен (точнее с локальной хтмл-страницы на онлайн сервер) поэтому нашел JSONP как решение, иначе получаю ошибку `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present...` И `crossDomain: true,` тоже не помогает

Comment: Хм... тогда вы можете либо посмотреть в сторону POST + [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) либо ждать пока кто-то предложит решение вашей изначальной задачи (с разбиением данных)

Comment: Оказывается что если `dataType: 'jsonp'` убрать то хотя ошибка в консоле и появляется но данные на сервере все же сохраняются т.е. запрос выполняется несмотря на разные "домены", вопрос только будет ли оно так работать во всех браузерах

Comment: @stckvrw: `иначе получаю ошибку No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present...` Вы рано сдались. Конечно, с CORS требуется немного пошаманить, зато можно отправлять не только GET, но POST запросы, а также идентификатор сессионной куки, если используется заголовок/прагма `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:"true"` (т.е. быть авторизированным не только на домене, но и на поддомене к которому вы обращаетесь). Если на сервер передаются кастомные заголовки, к примеру, `X_REQUESTED_WITH` указывающий, что это ajax-запрос, то браузер сперва отсылает уточняющий OPTIONS запрос

Comment: в попытке получить от сервера заголовок `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` с перечнем разрешённых кастомных заголовков, а уже только потом шлёт основной запрос, в вашем случае `POST`. OPTIONS можно ловить и web-сервером (прописать увсловия в конфигах Nginx или Apache), а не вашем приложением на php. Предлагаю [посмотреть видео](https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/2136/) с конференции Yandex про CORS и подводные камни связанные с ним. Замечено, что отладку CORS лучше всего производить chromium-подобными браузерами, ибо браузер выдаёт более информатиыне сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: @stckvrw: Если хотите, могу оформить в виде ответа с примерами на php.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте POST запрос вместо GET запроса. Хотя, лимит на длину тела при POST запросе есть, вы почти наверняка в него не упретесь (обычно, максимальный размер запроса измеряется мегабайтами). Для того, чтобы отправить AJAX POST запрос средствами jQuery можно использовать вот такой код:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mydomain.com/myhandler.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {}
    // Другие параметры запроса...
});
```

**UPD**:

Если вы действительно хотите использовать JSONP, то вы не сможете передавать данные через POST запросы. JSONP просто не работает таким образом, увы.

Comment: А какой лимит все же при POST запросе?

Comment: Зависит от настроек вебсервера. На практике, это значение имеет порядок мегабайта.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, от браузера это не зависит (по крайней мере я никогда с такими проблемами не сталкивался). Вы поймите, что запрос с телом в 1 мегабайт может содержать строку длинной порядка миллиона символов. У вас действительно такие большие запросы?

Comment: Что то все же не так. Попробовал отправить post-запрос: где то 9150 символов пропускает, а уже 9200 — нет. При этом на сервере у хостинг-провайдера стоит post_max_size 8MB т.е. должно пропускать около 8 млн. Где еще может быть лимит?

Comment: Смотрите логи ошибок apache, там должна быть какая-то информация о проблеме

Comment: Уже выяснил: оказывается все хорошо, просто в строке которую отправляю несколько десятков знаков % (так нужно). Если их убираю или оставляю всего несколько тогда пропускает строку любой длины. Не проверял после какого кол-ва % блокирует. На этот символ есть какие то ограничения?

Comment: @stckvrw, мне такие ограничения не известны. Проблема, скорее в том, что символ `%` используется для экранирования в URL. Возможно, хотя и маловероятно, проблема вызвана какими-то комбинациями сразу после символов `%`.

Answer (score 0):

После того как вы разбили строку на массив можно этот массив и отправить:

**UPD:**
Перед отправкой первой части необходимо объявить переменную с timestamp'ом отправки первого куска и добавлять его параметром ко всем частям сообщения.

```
var messageId = new Date().getTime()
stringArray.each(function(index, item) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://mydomain.com/myhandler.php?part='+ index + '&messageId=' + messageId,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'myCallback',
        data: {item},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
```

После отправки, на контроллере собираете строку.
Можно воспользоваться обычным for, для того, чтобы отслеживать последний элемент массива и отправлять параметр last.
Если возникнут проблемы с порядком при получении запросов, можно добавить в `$.ajax` параметр `async: false`.
**P.S.:** для увеличения полезной нагрузки GET-запроса, после отладки, можно имена параметров сократить.